# Passing Batch output to exe

Tags: c++, parsing, batch-file, output

I would like to create a batch file that is able to send its output directly to and exe, which will handle the information.

For example: I ping google.com 100 times and want to parse **each** response with an exe file builded in c++.

It is important for me to do this real time, so it is not an option to read the full log file after pinging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pipe.

```
ping google.com -c 100 | ./path/to/exe.exe
```

if you batch file contains `ping google.com -c 100` you can just pipe the batch file itself

```
file.bat | ./path/to/exe.exe
```

Pipe will send the output to stdin of your exe file. So read it from STDIN. [`std::cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/) will do.

Comment: i tried this before, but how can I reach the data with c++? It is not in argv

Comment: Read from STDIN. Use [`std::cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/).